# If my Angular Controller is not using any $scope, then how do i do 2 way data binding in my directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I have been using Angular without `$scope`

**Controller:**

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('requestController', requestController);

requestController.$inject = ['$location','requestService'];

function requestController($location, requestService) {

    var vm = this;
    //......
    var detail = {}; 
    detail.program.....  
}
```

**HTML page shows value**

```
{{detail.program.code}}    shows   DGAT  on page ...  thus it has value
```

**Pass it into a Directive**

```
   <com-code progCode="detail.program.code"></com-code>
```

**Directive in which is supposed to take value in as two way binding**

```
(function () {
    var injectParams = ['customerService', '$sce'];

    var comCode = function (customerService, $sce) {
        return {
            replace: true,
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                progCode: "="
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                console.log('scope.progCode',scope.progCode);  // UNDEFINED

            }
        };
    };

    comCode.$inject = injectParams;
    angular.module('app').directive('comCode', comCode)
}());
```

1. Why is this `undefined`?
2. Is it from the lack of `$scope` in controller?
3. Does `progCode` as 2 way data binding become part of the scope in the directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becouse you didn't added in your controller set your detail in $scope

```
$scope.detail = detail;
```

But get data from $sope in directive - is bag practice

Comment: Why do i need to use $scope when controlleras  syntax made it clear to not use $scope injected in ... thus   very common to do   var vm = this; in the controller and never use $scope   ...  so i'm lost of why

Comment: yes, or use this. `this.detail = detail`, and in directive set `scope: {progCode : '=progCode'},`

Comment: [note](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) Note: These =attr attributes in the scope option of directives are normalized just like directive names. To bind to the attribute in <div bind-to-this="thing">, you'd specify a binding of =bindToThis.

Comment: mybe create in directive only code `<com-code code="detail.program.code"></com-code>` and set in directive scope: {progCode : '=code'}

Answer (score 0):

While using directive in HTML, attrs should be **dash seperated**. So,

```
<com-code prog-code="detail.program.code"></com-code>
```

should work (assuming you have everything else in place)!

Comment: oh,  the progcode is an attr ... , i thought  =  was for 2 way,  and @ is for attr

Comment: @JeremyMiller no, all are called attributes only irrespective of whatever type (`=`/`&`/`@`). And all of them should be camelCase in directive but dash-seperated in HTML

Comment: Do I need to add $scope to my controller like the other person said?

Comment: @JeremyMiller nah, it works with `vm` too which is `controllerAs` syntax.. (though I wonder why your HTML directly contains `{{detail.something}}` and not `{{vm.detail.something}}`)

Comment: I didn't want the question post to be super long so i hacked away some of the code ,  it is done that way from another developer  so in controller i see  `var detail = {}`  then   `detail.Program = {}`   then it is later hydrated

Comment: trying to do a plunker without $scope in the controller i forked and having trouble getting value on the page    http://plnkr.co/edit/7pr8pFSeKMQuL37jRpZv?p=preview

Comment: @JeremyMiller here you go: http://plnkr.co/edit/L9AbO9qSPbF4giz018vT?p=preview (working plunker)

Comment: Hey ,  on my code (not plunker)  i get  `detail.program.Code`  i prints it out literally  not the value...

Comment: @JeremyMiller you need to have `ng-controller="requestController as vm"` and then use `vm.detail.program...`

Comment: @JeremyMiller you must not be using controller as then that is the reason your variable is not resolved

Comment: I can get  1 way binding to work ...  pass in with {{}} and then use   @  instead of =  ...  why would 2 way not work?

Comment: @JeremyMiller its not about one way or 2 way unless you bind your controller with `this` and use `controller as` in html you will not get bindings between the controller and view. once you get the bindings right one way or 2 way its choice of implementation

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the controller as syntax see this [PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/3JoLAJqgyNNNUFDIkODN?p=preview)

```
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
      <h4>valBit: {{main.data.valBit}}</h4>
    <my-code input-code="main.data.valBit"></my-code>
    <p ng-if="main.data.valBit == 1">
      part of my form,  with ngmessage etc... $erroretc... 
    </p>  
    </div>
```

When you don't use scope you need to use `this` for bindings in controller and use `controller as` syntax in route or html then use that reference to call values

Answer (score 0):

you use controllerAs with the vm variable, but here you don't bind the detail variable into your vm. So you can't pass the detail to your directive.

To do that bind details to your view/model (vm) variable:

```
vm.detail = detail;
```

Into the view bind vm.detail to your directive:

```
<com-code progCode="vm.detail.program.code"></com-code>
```